# Beamer 3.30 with helvet - Problem with upper-case Greek

Tags: beamer, fonts, greek

Since I updated to latex beamer 3.30 last week, I do not get upper-case Greek letters anymore with the "helvet" package - they are replaced by black boxes instead. This is an example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{helvet}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
$\Gamma \neq \Theta \neq \Omega$

$\gamma, \theta, \omega$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Lower-case Greek letters do work properly.

Below is how it looks what the example above produces and what we get when outcommenting the helvet package. Note that also some mathematical symbols seem to be screwed. For instance, in the examples below with helvet package, "\neq" looks more like a non-math "=" with a slash through it rather than a single symbol.

With helvet:

[image: with helvet package]

Without helvet:

[image]

Comment: I've got a good idea where the issue might be, at least in terms of changes in `beamer`. I'll do some testing.

Comment: The `\OT1/phv/m/n/10` font doesn't have Greek letters. You get them with `\usepackage{tgheros}`, instead, but the final result will be quite poor, since uppercase Greek will be sans serif and lowercase, on the contrary, serif.

Comment: Should be fixed in the current release (v3.31). Can you test?

Comment: @JosephWright: It works fine. Thank you very much!

Comment: @JosephWright: Should this question be closed?

Comment: @Werner I guess either that or answered: which do you prefer?

Comment: @JosephWright: I don't know what the fix is/was. However, if it's temporary in nature, and a package update solves the problem, then I guess closure is in order. Other's can weigh in as well.

Comment: @Werner We tend to close recently if an update fixes the problem with OT + custom *due to a bug* message. I guess this looks like one of those.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was about a bug that has been fixed in v3.31 and later of `beamer`.