# beamer 3.58 problem with helvet and lmodern - problem with upper-case Greek

Tags: beamer, greek, lmodern, uppercase

I have a problem similar to the one asked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/138898/beamer-3-30-with-helvet-problem-with-upper-case-greek). 
My minimal working example looks like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{helvet}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
$\Gamma \neq \Theta \neq \Omega$

$\gamma, \theta, \omega$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The result looks like this with lmodern (line 2 in the mwe) in it:

[image]

and like this without lmodern

[image]

Is this still a bug in beamer?

Answer (score 1):

It may still be a bug in `beamer`, but I wouldn't know, you can open an issue on the [`beamer` bug tracker](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues) if you want.

Otherwise this workaround seems to work

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usefonttheme[]{serif}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
$\Gamma \neq \Theta \neq \Omega$

$\gamma, \theta, \omega$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That workaround works for me too. Thanks :) Will open an issue for beamer nevertheless.

Answer (score 1):

for the sake of completeness, I'm answering my own question with an answer I got from the beamer bug tracker: using the professionalfonts theme solves the problem. (see also [this github issue](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/598)).

Here is the minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{helvet}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
$\Gamma \neq \Theta \neq \Omega$

$\gamma, \theta, \omega$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```